# templateSelection called two time (Select2 Kartik- yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm a new Yii2.I've this bug, I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Bug is very simple templateSelection called two time. this is my code.

if I submit somethings in select2, templateSelection called two time.

```
echo Select2::widget([
                            'name' => 'blogId',
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for [![enter image description here][1]][1] ...'],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true,
                                'minimumInputLength' => 1,
                                'ajax' => [
                                    'url' => Url::to(['/controller/action']),
                                    'dataType' => 'json',
                                    'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }'),
                                    'processResults' => new JsExpression($resultsJs),
                                ],
                                'templateResult' => new JsExpression($formatRepo),
                                'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function(params) { console.log("tst");}'),
                            ],

                        ]);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found reponse myself by debuging select2.full.js

problem is right here.
just remove this code. it call two time because it's nested function.

```
    this.$element.on('change.select2', function () { self.dataAdapter.current(function (data) { 
//self.trigger('selection:update', { 
data: data }); 
// }); 
});
```